# How to differentiate mini dataframes appened to a bigger dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a bigger dataframe from others dataframes, But I need to indentificate the them separately. I want to create a new column with a index of every dataframe.

```
 frames = [dataTotal,dataFrame]
 dataTotal = dataTotal.append(dataFrame, ignore_index=False, sort=False)
```

I tried use the pd.contact with the atributte key, but it doesn't work since the dataframes are in different sizes.

What I have to do?

Example:
I've this dataframe, and a want to append other to it, and create a index to differentiate them

```
 name       LastName                                                    
  0  Vitor      Albres  
  1  Matheus    Wilson 
  2  Andrew     George  
  3  Filipe     Dircksen
  4  Eli        Matthew
```

Add a other dataframe

```
 name       LastName                                                    
  0  Ana      Lee  
  1  Renato   Cristian 
  2  Joe      Jonh
```

To create something like

```
 data_id  name       LastName                                                    
    0  0  Vitor      Albres  
       1  Matheus    Wilson 
       2  Andrew     George  
       3  Filipe     Dircksen
       4  Eli        Matthew
    1  0  Ana        Lee  
       1  Renato     Cristian 
       2  Joe        Jonh
```

passing the atribute key, doesn't work, 'cause it say I can't concat dataframes with different levels. I don't know if I make ir wrong or something

Comment: Please share a sample input with expected output for better understanding.

Comment: I edited to make it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with arg `key`:

```
In [1831]: df1
Out[1831]: 
      name  LastName
0    Vitor    Albres
1  Matheus    Wilson
2   Andrew    George
3   Filipe  Dircksen
4      Eli   Matthew

In [1832]: df2
Out[1832]: 
     name  LastName
0     Ana       Lee
1  Renato  Cristian
2     Joe      Jonh

In [1830]: df_list = [df1, df2]

In [1833]: df =  pd.concat(df_list, keys=range(len(df_list)))
```

Then name the `Multiindex` using `df.index.names`:

```
In [1837]: df.index.names = ['data_id', '']

In [1838]: df
Out[1838]: 
              name  LastName
data_id                     
0       0    Vitor    Albres
        1  Matheus    Wilson
        2   Andrew    George
        3   Filipe  Dircksen
        4      Eli   Matthew
1       0      Ana       Lee
        1   Renato  Cristian
        2      Joe      Jonh
```

Comment: What's the "l" used in `keys=range(len(l))`
 stands for?
I tried something lie  `dataTotal = pd.concat(df_list, keys=['x', 'y'])` but got the error: 
'Cannot concat indices that do not have the same number of levels'

Comment: Sorry, its a typo. Updated my answer.

Comment: I keep getting the erro **Cannot concat indices that do not have the same number of levels**

Comment: I've tested on the sample you provided in your question. It works nicely for me.

Comment: The real one I am trying to make is complicated than the example, basically I am using a for loop to create new dataframes from a json and insert them one by one into the bigger one, somethin like `frames = [dataTotal,dataFrame] `
 `dataTotal = pd.concat(frames, keys=range(len(frames)))` the problem must be in something like there